# GridView inside a ViewPager

Tags: java, android

I can't swipe/move to next page without me putting my finger to an empty space in the gridview, anyone encountered this?

Comment: I have the same probleam,do you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you subclass ViewPager and overriding the onInterceptTouchEvent() method. The following checks for swipes in the X direction to allow for vertical scrolling if necessary. Not sure if it solves your problem completely but you can give an attempt.

```
private static final int minSwipeDistance = 30;
private float mTouchX;

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    boolean response = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(event);
    float x = event.getX();
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        mTouchX = x;
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        float dX = Math.abs(x - mTouchX);
        if (dX > minSwipeDistance)
            return true;
        break;
    }
    return response;
}
```